# What is the difference between assigning a function via "this" vs. "prototype"?

Tags: javascript, oop, function, prototype, constructor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Use of 'prototype' vs. 'this' in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/310870/use-of-prototype-vs-this-in-javascript)

I am confused with these two type of adding a method to a function. Let me explain with an example.

```
var foo = function(){
    this.bar = function(){alert('I am a method')}
}

foo.prototype.baz = function(){alert('I am another method')}

var car = new foo();
```

Now at this point we can use baz and bar methods for car. Well, but what is the difference between them. What is the nuance adding a method to function's prototype or it's constructor.

Thanks..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Functions assigned to the `prototype` will be shared by all instances; functions assigned in the constructor will have a separate function object per instance.

Also, functions assign in the constructor can use the constructor's variables and parameters.

For example:

```
var foo = function(param){
    this.bar = function() { alert('I can see a parameter: ' + param); };
}

foo.prototype.baz = function() { alert('I can't see foo's parameters'); };

var car = new foo("Hi there!");
car.bar();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var foo = function(){
    this.bar = function(){alert('I am a method')}
}
```

This gives each foo instance a bar method of its own. So,

```
 var car1 = new foo();
 var car2 = new foo();
 car2.bar = //new function definition here.
 //car1.bar doesn't change.
```

In the second case:

```
foo.prototype.baz = function(){alert('I am another method')}
```

You are attaching a function to the prototype chain of the **function foo**. So, each instance gets the same method. <strike>Changing **baz** would change the function on each instance as each instance inherits the same function.</strike>

The advantage of the second approach is clear in terms of inheritance. Also, in the first approach, since you are attaching a method to each specific instance, it won't scale if you are creating several **foo instances** as each instance would unnecessarily have a copy of the same method.

Comment: **Wrong**.  Re-assigning an instance member will hide the prototype for that instance.

Comment: So after these two satisfactory answer, I will understand that, if adding a method with prototype all instances shares the method and this is about memory management issues. Am I right?

Comment: @Lorenzo: Unless you're creating millions of instances, don't worry about it.

Comment: @SLaks I understand that reassigning an instance member will hide the prototype. But i meant that changes to the function baz are live meaning the instances automatically inherit the new function definition.

Comment: @Rajat: Do you mean changes to the prototype? If so, you should clarify.

Comment: @SLaks Yeah, thats what I meant. In hindsight, I think my sentence construction was a little confusing. Thanks for the correction though.